# Disable loge in check for: Encode-Explorer

Tags: php

To list files on my web i use: Encode-Explorer

There are some features for upload, create dir and delete. To have access to upload files you must be logged in.

I have my own user system and just want everyone who can enter this page to be able to upload files. No extra login is required.

This is the whole script:
https://github.com/marekrei/encode-explorer/blob/master/index.php

I have tried to set `return true;` for some options:

```
public static function isAccessAllowed()
{
    if(!GateKeeper::isLoginRequired() || GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn())
        return true;
    return false; //THIS I CHANGED TO TRUE
}

public static function isUploadAllowed(){
    if(EncodeExplorer::getConfig("upload_enable") == true && GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn() == true && GateKeeper::getUserStatus() == "admin")
        return true;
    return false; //THIS I CHANGED TO TRUE
}
```

When i change this.. i was able to see the HTML for upload, but the function wont upload anything. What more do i have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
public static function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['ee_user_name'], $_SESSION['ee_user_pass']))
    {
        if(GateKeeper::isUser($_SESSION['ee_user_name'], $_SESSION['ee_user_pass']))
            return true;
    }
    return true; //DEFAULT FALSE
}

public static function isAccessAllowed()
{
    if(!GateKeeper::isLoginRequired() || GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn())
        return true;
    return true; //DEFAULT FALSE
}

public static function isUploadAllowed(){
    if(EncodeExplorer::getConfig("upload_enable") == true && GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn() == true && GateKeeper::getUserStatus() == "admin")
        return true;
    return true; //DEFAULT FALSE
}

public static function isNewdirAllowed(){
    if(EncodeExplorer::getConfig("newdir_enable") == true && GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn() == true && GateKeeper::getUserStatus() == "admin")
        return true;
    return true; //DEFAULT FALSE
}

public static function isDeleteAllowed(){
    if(EncodeExplorer::getConfig("delete_enable") == true && GateKeeper::isUserLoggedIn() == true && GateKeeper::getUserStatus() == "admin")
        return true;
    return true; //DEFAULT FALSE
}
```

Comment: You know that this kind of code : `if (myCondition) { return true; } return false;` can be replaced by `return myCondition;` ?